# Android Social Integration Facebook is not working under my apps App id and key secret

Tags: android, facebook

I working on one social integration project using guide of git-hub, but my problem is that it if i change application id and secret key with my application then it not post message and upload image means in my app-id and secret key it not update it status after authentication.

```
    - my status and review in on (yes)
    - my class name and package name is up-to-date
    - i got my hash key using Open SSL and used that one.
```

i don't know now where is the problem,please help me anyone.it may be possible with hash key ? how to solve it please help quick.

i got following error show in following screen-shot.

[image]

how to solve that, and got that permission ?

Answer (score 1):

Facebook integration

Running Sample:

1. First of all download Facebook SDK from here link.

   https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk
2. Create a Facebook application link here to get a Facebook APP ID for your application.

   https://www.facebook.com/login.php?next=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fapps%2F
3. You need to create a key hash of your signature from android debug.keystore (for the development stage).
4. For this First download OpenSSL from link here and extract to a folder (in my case, c:\openssl) and follow these steps.

   ```
       http://code.google.com/p/openssl-for-windows/downloads/list
   ```

steps

C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.6.0_07\bin>keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey
 -keystore "C:\Users\arun.r.android\debug.keystore" > C:\openssl\bin\debug.txt
Enter keystore password:  android

C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.6.0_07\bin>keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey
 -keystore "C:\Users\arun.r.android\debug.keystore" > C:\openssl\bin\debug.txt
Enter keystore password:  android

C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.6.0_07\bin>cd..

C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.6.0_07>cd..

C:\Program Files\Java>cd..

C:\Program Files>cd..

C:>cd openssl

C:\openssl>cd bin

C:\openssl\bin>openssl sha1 -binary debug.txt >debug_sha.txt

C:\openssl\bin>openssl base64 -in debug_sha.txt >debug_base64.txt

Go to same location and copy key

sample my key---->  ktbpgIBduSi6sQbdoT1IBJHMpoI=

xwnBSKCMTnoDlP00sj/D2wnm5jM=

1. Download the project from here and import it in the eclipse.
2. Import Facebook SDK project in your eclipse (which you have downloaded in step 1) and make it a library project.
3. Add this library project into your sample android application.
4. Open Constants.java file and change FB_APP_ID variable value with your FB APP ID.
5. Build your android application and install on your android device.